# how long can a logic apps webhook wait?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

we are evaluating logic apps for long running workflows

our process is as follows

1. once we receive a request (http request trigger), we call another service with the webhook action sending a callback url, now the process might take any where between 10 to 15 days to complete.

Question

1. can the logic app wait for 10 to 15 days ?
2. what happens if the callback does not happen ?

Thanks -Nen

Answer (score 1):

A single HTTP request from Logic Apps will time out after 2 minutes. The default run time limit for all synchronous actions in multi-tenant Logic App is 2 minutes.

1. can the logic app wait for 10 to 15 days --> no
2. what happens if the callback does not happen ? --> [Action
   patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#action-patterns)

check below links -

[calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701)

[Limits and configuration information for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config)

Answer (score 0):

There are two points that need to be made when answering your question.

**Firstly**, the standard amount of time that a HTTP trigger can run for is two minutes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#run-duration-and-retention-history-limits), but, that's when the request/response architecture is synchronous based.  If you want to fire it in an asynchronous way (like you do) then you need to provide a `Response` to the calling application prior to the two minute timeout.  Like thus ..

[image: Flow]

**Secondly**, You can see from the above image that a delay has been running for **11 minutes** at the time of posting this answer which is more than the 2 minutes restriction if the response wasn't provided back.

I suspect (and would need to confirm but it would take me 10 days) that a webhook will perform for your full 10 to 15 days given there is absolutely no evidence to show it doesn't (i.e. the documentation does not explicitly state it).  I believe it will stick to the 90 day period as per the full length of any multi-tenant Logic App implementation.